# Injecting different services in Grails

Tags: grails, dependency-injection

Is it possible, to have two services implement the same interface and to decide at runtime what service to to inject for the interface in Grails?

For example

```
MyAService implements MyInterface {
...
}

MyBService implements MyInterface {
...
}
```

Other services then just have a reference to MyInterface and you decide based on config setting or whatever what service to inject?

Answer (score 6):

Grails uses auto-inject by name for convention-based injection like `def fooService`, and artifacts like services are auto-registered at startup. You have more control if you configure a bean and its dependencies in `resources.groovy`, and can use Groovy code to apply logic.

But I'd keep things simple and do the work in `BootStrap.groovy`. Add a public field (e.g. `def myService`) or a private field and a setter (e.g. `void setMyService(service) { this.myService = service }` in the destination class. Then in BootStrap, dependency-inject all of the possible candidates and manually inject the correct one. Something like

```
class BootStrap {

   def myAService
   def myBService
   def theDestinationBean

   def init = { servletContext ->
      if (<some condition>) {
         theDestinationBean.myService = myAService
      }
      else {
         theDestinationBean.myService = myBService
      }
   }
}
```

Since it's Groovy, you probably don't need the interface, but it doesn't hurt and can give you a bit of compile-time safety.

Comment: Not bad.  But just say I have a lot of classes like theDestinationBean how does this scale?

Comment: One option would be to add `def grailsApplication` and retrieve beans from the ApplicationContext manually, e.g. `def otherDest = grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean('<bean name>')`. You could define the bean names and loop through them applying the logic as needed. Spring has an `InitializingBean` interface with an `afterPropertiesSet` method that you use to do work once all deps have been set. You couldn't use that here since you're doing work after Spring does its, but you might create a similar interface (or just a convention for a method to call) and call it once you're done.

Answer (score 2):

In my project, I use the `resources.groovy`

```
if(myconf == "A") {
  myInterfaceService = ref('myAService')
} else {
  myInterfaceService = ref('myBService')
}
```

But I think it is a bad practice because both `myAService` and `myBService` are instancied even if only one is really used.

I would rather have only one service as grails service and different different implementations will lie in the `src` directories and then either:

- use the `resources.groovy` to fill the service with correct implementation
- or make my service implements `afterPropertiesSet` from `InitializingBean` interface